# asp.net mvc do nothing after several loop in ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, genetic-algorithm

I am working on the implementation of **Genetic Algorithm** 
i do the code using ASP.NET MVC4 web application.

*Input user :*

1. Number of taxi available
2. Max generation
3. Max convergence

My code works perfectly if user input the number of taxi available less then 30 and max generation less then 100 based on testing.

**The problem is** : if user input exceeds the condition above, then my code only work about 18 - 40 iteration loop then it do nothing.

can someone explain me how to solve this ?
i've done some research related to this problem, and the answer is to add async in the controller, but it didn't help, my problem still exist.

here's my overall controller workflow :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ProsesGADTO dto)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            - Some Genetic Algorithm Process

                while (maxGeneration > countGeneration && checkConvergence < maxConvergence)
                {
                    countGeneration++;
                    - Extended genetic algorithm process

                }

             return RedirectToAction("HasilGA");
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

i edited the question to make it more simple.
and i didn't use async for the final implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "then it do nothing"? Does it exit the method or hangs? How can you tell it does nothing?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov yep hang maybe, i made a break point in the code, after 18 iteration visual studio debug the process didn't paused at the break point.

Comment: Try to write logs in the action to see what it stops. Write log in the beginning and end of the method and inside major code blocks. Also symptoms are similar to a deadlock. Maybe you can post your solution? Why do you need Task.Delay?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov 
error logs or ? do i need to log like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811678/c-sharp-mvc-logging-method-execution-and-performance ? sorry, i am new to c# programming.

i don't really need task.delay, i just run through the same problem and they fixed it using task.delay so i tried it too, but it didn't work.

Comment: You could setup NLog for instance to log to a file. Do you any other async operations in your algorithm? Try to comment out some blocks of you algorithm to narrow down the issue. Try also run in console app project to see of it makes any difference.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov
okay i will try to log it and comment some block.

"Do you any other async operations in your algorithm?" i don't really know if async helps my problem or not.

Comment: I don't see a reason why async should be a solution. Just if you have more async operations you could create a deadlock if use it in a wrong way. You could also go through every iteration with a debugger to see what exactly happens. It is useful skill to be able to troubleshoot issues.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov even tho i don't use async, it still stop and do nothing around 30 iteration :(

Comment: Can you post you solution somewhere? Maybe on GitHub or Bitbucket?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov i've posted it in bitbucket.can i have ur email, so i can share it with you ?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov check your email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139025/discussion-between-andrii-litvinov-and-shasapo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your code. You need to find out why it never meet the condition to exit that loop.